# Is it possible to use only hardware keyboard to edit TextField in Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, keyboard, textfield

I am developing Android applications for PDA devices (such Datalogic https://www.datalogic.com/eng/retail-manufacturing-transportation-logistics-healthcare/mobile-computers/skorpio-x5-pd-887.html). These devices have hardware keyboards and I woudl like to get input from those keyboards without displaying the soft keyboard.
The issue is that when the soft keyboard is hidden, the key strokes do not get to the TextField widgets, event if they have the focus on. If I use this code:

```
          child: TextField(
            keyboardType: TextInputType.none,
            showCursor: true,
            cursorWidth: 5,
            cursorRadius: const Radius.elliptical(10, 10),
            cursorColor: Colors.blue,
          ),
```

then the text fields look like in the image below, but no matter what hardware key I press, it does not alter the value of the current TextField.

[image: TextField without keyboard]

If instead I use

```
          child: TextField(
            keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
            showCursor: true,
            cursorWidth: 5,
            cursorRadius: const Radius.elliptical(10, 10),
            cursorColor: Colors.blue,
          ),
```

then I will have the keyboard on and hardware keystrokes will alter the value of the TextField  and I can input data through the hardware keyboard (but not all keys are working properly - this is the second part of my question):

[image: TextField with keyboard]

The main question is:

1. Is there a way to send hardware key strokes to the TextField without showing the soft keyboard?

and I would also need to know:

2. Why some key strokes (such as letters on shift mode) are not taken into account by TextField? Key strokes are detected by the applicaiton if I use `ServicesBinding.instance.keyboard.addHandler(_onKeyPress);` but they have no effect whatsoever on the TextField.